# Install rpy2 with custom R installation

Tags: r, rpy2

I have a custom installation of R in

~/R-3.2.2/bin/

When I run

```
sudo pip install rpy2
```

I get

```
    Warning: Tried to guess R's HOME but no command (R) in the PATH.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-ITKmkR/rpy2/setup.py", line 330, in <module>
    ri_ext = getRinterface_ext()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-ITKmkR/rpy2/setup.py", line 231, in getRinterface_ext
    r_home = _get_r_home()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-ITKmkR/rpy2/setup.py", line 63, in _get_r_home
    r_home = r_home.split(os.linesep)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r_home' referenced before assignment
```

I have found no answer to this problem, even though it appears in several posts. Here is what I tried

- add the R executable to the PATH

  export PATH=$PATH:/home/R-3.2.2/bin/
  did not work
- export R_HOME with the same value: did not work
- `echo export PATH=$PATH:/home/R-3.2.2/bin/ >> ~/.bashrc
  source ~/.bashrc`

did not work.

On the other hand the "problem" seems solved here
https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/283/rpy2-installation-error-when-r-output

How to install rpy2 correctly?

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because of an [issue in rpy2](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/353/error-during-installation-if-r-not-in-the) (just fixed).
Otherwise, it might be because R is either not in the PATH as you think it is, or may be you do not have the permission to run it.

Try:

```
# assert that the R executable is where you think it is
~/R-3.2.2/bin/R --version
# set the PATH
export PATH=${PATH}:~/R-3.2.2/bin/
# unset R_HOME if needed
unset R_HOME
# install rpy2
pip install rpy2
```